# present view controller on selecting tabbar item

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, popover

how to present view controller when tabbar item clicked.
I just want to display as a popover .
Using storyboard

i found that solution but this is not working

```
  AddImage *yourViewController= (AddImage*)  [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];

    CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.bounds.size.height;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tabBarHeight, tabBarHeight);
    [AddImage presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                                                             inView:self.tabBarController.tabBar
                                                           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Comment: Implement `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item` tabbar controller delegate and add the code to show popup inside this delegate method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose
1) set the delegate of the tabbar

2) implement the method : `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`

3) now display popover for the specific item

Comment: where do i set  delegate of tabbar ? i mean in which view controller?

Comment: to the view controller on which you need to display the popup.

Comment: if I want to stay on same tab and perform some action . for example i am on tab 2 . and if i click on tab 3 then i want to handle action of tab 3  on tab 2. then ?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: I solved this by adding  - (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if(viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]){
       // self.selectedIndex = prevTab; //only change in this method
        
        NSLog(@"not changing");
        
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
    
}

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

Create a class that inherits from `UITabBarController` and set the protocol `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

```
class CustomTabController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.delegate = self 
   }
}
```

Implement the method `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool`.

From there, a simple `if-else` statement to check what the current controller class is will suffice.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is YourViewController {
        self.present(YourViewController(), animated: true)
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```